# Javascript calculation from html input id always results in 1

Tags: javascript

I'm running into an error when performing a calculation on submit using javascript. The pay_amount input submits '1' and total_charged submits '4.95' regardless of what the value of pay_amount is.

Here is the html:

```
<form method="POST" action="example-post-url.php" autocomplete="off" name="form" id="form">

    <input type="text" id="pay_amount" name="pay_amount" value="1,794.00"/>  
    <input type="hidden" id="total_charged" name="total_charged" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submitCard();" id="submitButton"/>

</form>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script>
    function submitCard(){

        var payment = parseFloat(document.getElementById('pay_amount').value);
        var fee = ((payment*0.035)+3.95);
        var total = payment + fee;
        document.getElementById('total_charged').value = total.toFixed(2);

        document.form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

I've tried replacing var payment with the code below thinking it was an issue with commas, but I'm still running into problems.

```
var payment = document.getElementById('pay_amount').value.replace(/,/g, '');
```

What in the world is going on here?

Comment: I really doubt that, with that code there, "pay_amount" is being submitted to the server as "1".

Answer (score 3):

The `parseFloat()` routine stops parsing when it sees something that's not part of a valid number. In your case, that's the comma.

When you change the code as you suggested in your post, you fix the comma problem but you leave the value as a string.  If you combine the two — get rid of the comma *and* call `parseFloat()` — it'll work better.

That said, if you're not going to be checking the payment and fee computation on the server, please post the URL for your e-commerce site once it's done.

Answer (score 1):

You should prevent the original submit

```
<form ... onsubmit="return false;" ...>

    ...

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="submitCard();" id="submitButton"/>
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submitCard();" id="submitButton"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<script>
    function submitCard(){

        var payment = parseFloat(document.getElementById('pay_amount').value);
        var fee = ((payment*0.035)+3.95);
        var total = payment + fee;
        document.getElementById('total_charged').value = total.toFixed(2);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

Instead of `document.forms.submit()` which is what you have right now.
This should be changed regardless of whether it solves the problem as `document.form` is undefined.

Comment: However your code is far more in adequacy with best practices and the OP should follow your advice, `document.form` is not undefined in this case since there is a form element named "form" in this document.

Comment: @Luc125 Didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, this has nothing to do with the `submit` event of the form, and more to do with how the string type of the `value` attribute is being converted into a number for math operations.

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qGYvw/1/) for how to use `parseFloat()` better.

Here is the important part:

```
parseFloat(document.getElementById('pay_amount').value.replace(',', ''));
```

Comment: **REMEMBER** to remove the console.log() debugging statement before deploying to production.